# Javascript Searching an XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, search

For a project I am doing I have to search an XML file using Javascript and display the results of the search below. As an example, my XML file will contain students and other information as below:

```
<studentList>
<student>
    <idNumber>1102356</idNumber>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
    <surname>Leeder</surname>
    <course>Computing</course>
    <year>2008</year>
</student>
```

So if I search for 2008, it will display all of the students information for 2008.

I have created some code to display all students using onclick but it tries to open the results in a different page and doesn't display anything:

```
    var students;

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    //Search the XML file for the following catergories.
    for each (students in studentLib) {
        //Each catergory displayed in a table format.
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td>"+students.idNumber+"</td>");
        document.write("<td>"+students.firstName+"</td>");
        document.write("<td>"+students.surname+"</td>");
        document.write("<td>"+students.course+"</td>");
        document.write("<td>"+students.year+"</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
        }
    document.write("</table>");

    }
```

I'm just not sure how to write code for searching and displaying the results of an XML file and also doing it on the same page.

I have had a look around google but it uses really complex code when I have been taught a different method.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thank you